# Low-cost host for website that contains both dynamic and (many) static pages

Tags: amazon-s3, hosting

I have a website that contains both dynamic and static pages. The dynamic page is simple, which is mostly a search function through the existing static pages. The static pages are pre-generated HTML stored in AWS S3 and there are about a million of those. What are my choices of serving my website, at low cost if possible? Here are a few possibilities that do not seem to work:

1. AWS S3, but it (maybe) only serves static website.
2. A normal web host like heroku, but I'm not sure if it can store millions of pages.

P.S. I would like to add new static pages to the website on each day, so desirably there should be some way to update the website database/pages.

Comment: What does the search look like? Is it e.g. purely in client side JavaScript? Then it would still be a static page as far as S3 is concerned even if the client then decides to do dynamic things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the search functionality. For example, if call an external API/backend you can simply choose a static hosting provider with pricing that suits you. Otherwise, you can simply choose a regular hosting provider, but just check again for a suitable pricing one.